# NullPointerException thrown by Gant when compiling upgraded grails app

Tags: grails

I upgraded my Grails 1.3.7 app to Grails 2.2 by doing the following

1. Set the `GRAILS_HOME` variable to the location of Grails 2.2
2. Edited the path to refer to this location
3. Ran `grails upgrade`
4. Edited `application.properties` to remove all plugin references
5. Edited `Build.config` to create a `plugins` closure to refer to my plugins
6. Ran `grails clean`
7. Ran `grails compile`

Step 7 fails with the following error:

```
C:\code\querium\AppServer-grails-2>grails compile --stacktrace
| Compiling 98 source files
| Warning The [executeSafely] action accepts a parameter of type [groovy.lang.Closure] which has not been marked with @V
alidateable.  Data binding will still be applied to this command object but the instance will not be validateable.

       def executeSafely(Closure c) {
       ^
| Warning The [executeSafely] action accepts a parameter of type [groovy.lang.Closure] which has not been marked with @V
alidateable.  Data binding will still be applied to this command object but the instance will not be validateable.

        def executeSafely(Closure c) {
    ^
| Warning The [increment] action accepts a parameter of type [java.util.Map] which has not been marked with @Validateabl
e.  Data binding will still be applied to this command object but the instance will not be validateable.

        def increment(Map map, String t, int index) {
    ^
| Compiling 98 source files.
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Compilation Failed (NOTE: Stack trace has be
en filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6_closure7.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:48)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6_closure7.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy.withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy:69)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:47)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:46)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:1
85)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Compilation Failed
```

I am not sure where to real error is, and how to correct it. I am happy to ignore the warnings, unless there is a good reason to fix them. (If so, how?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the NPE, but the warnings are due to public methods in a controller. Controllers can't be called from application code, so public methods don't make sense. In 2.0+ actions can be methods now in addition to closures, so your helper methods are being misinterpreted as controller actions. Make them private and the warnings will go away, and with luck the NPE too.

There is upgrading information in the docs btw :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer (so to speak)! Where in the docs is the upgrading information? It was not at all obvious when I looked at the grails site...

Comment: See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html and the first three topics at http://grails.org/doc/latest/ What's new in Grails 2.2, What's new in Grails 2.1, and What's new in Grails 2.0 which each contain descriptions of new features and changes.